# Dynamic content and scroll position

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a kinda vertically long document, containing many boxes. These boxes can be removed dynamically via AJAX requests and i got some nasty behaviour - scroll position doesnt change, so if i have 100 boxes, read 20th box content and 5 boxes on the  top has been removed position jumps to 25th box, but the same `$(window).scrollTop()` position (for example all boxes are the same size).

So my question is what is the best practice to jump back to original box after top content disapearing(in case i have varied box sizes)?

Answer (score 0):

Try determining the vertical position of the element that you want to scroll to, maybe give it a buffer so that you don't put that element at the very top of the scrolled view, then use scrollTop to navigate the page to the desired view.

Comment: >determining the vertical position of the element that you want to scroll to
hmm, dont understand it tbh, i need to detect box in some scroll position and then jump to that element poisition?